# Use shell variables while execution of the script

Tags: shell, sh

Objective is to create a script that give multiple choice to pick while executing

```
parameter1=$1
option1="ls -l"
option2="ls -R"
```

Execution command: `sh script.sh option1 $1` or `sh script.sh option2 $1`

I tried with `sh script.sh $option1 $1` but no luck

Comment: Are you using minimal `sh` (POSIX) or other shells `bash`?

Comment: i'm using `sh` (POSIX)

Comment: Why are you passing `$1` as a value? what is it supposed to contain?

Comment: it is a input variable, where i'm passing the values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use variables; use functions:

```
f=$1

# Ensure that f's value is only one of the predefined
# function names.
case $f in
   option1|option2) : ;;
   *) printf 'Invalid command\n' >&2; exit 1 ;;
esac

arg=$2

option1 () {
   ls -l "$1"
}

option2 () {
    ls -R "$1"
}

"$f" "$arg"
```

Then `sh script.sh option1 foo` will execute `option1 foo`, which will execute `ls -l foo`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you need to call the script `script.sh` with the `optionX` as an indirect references. For example `sh script.sh option1 $1` would do `ls -l $1`. Is that really what you want ??

Here is an example

```
parameter1=$1
parameter2=$2
option1="ls -l"
option2="ls -R"
eval parameter1=\$$parameter1

$parameter1  $parameter2
```

Then simply just run `sh script.sh option1 <something>`

Comment: This won't work in POSIX shell; `${!parameter1}` is a bashism.

Comment: @chepner Ah, I did not notice OP’s env is sh. There will be also another way is to use eval

Comment: This isn't quite safe; make sure that `$1` only has one of the valid variable names as its value first, otherwise your use of `eval` could execute arbitrary code. (E.g. `sh script.sh '#; rm -rf /'`)

Comment: (My own answer had a similar vulnerability, though not as severe.)